# How to run a a portion of a PHP script after 50 seconds?

Tags: php, loops, curl, time, while-loop

I have this script that uses curl to get a response from a web service. The response returned by curl is a url for checking the status of registration. The response is in JSON so it needs to be decoded first. After decoding, the status is being checked by getting the contents of the url. From the content, registration status is retrieved and displayed to let the user know . The registration may take up to 50 seconds so I need to check the status again after 50 seconds. sleep or usleep isn't applicable for this so what I want to do is to get the current time, pause/wait for 50 seconds and check for the status again. I want to do this using while loop but I'm having a problem doing this. Here's the code:

```
<?php
function sendRequest($url, $params)
{
    $request = curl_init($url); // initiate curl object
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); // use HTTP POST to send form data
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.
    $response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response
    curl_close ($request); // close curl object
    return $response;
}

function sendJSONRequest($url, $data)
{             
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);             
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT ,50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                       
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'X-MP-Version: 10072013')                      
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    ob_start();
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($result === false || $info['http_code'] == 400) {
      return "0";
    } else {
      return $result;
    }
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($ch);
}

function WriteLog($offer,$values)
{
    $Filename = "./reports/".$offer.date('Ym').".txt";
    $fh = fopen($Filename, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $filecontent = date('Y-m-d G:i').',';
    $filecontent .= $values;
    $filecontent .= PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($fh,$filecontent);
    fclose($fh);
}

// Get Variables sent from websites
$uname = $_GET['un'];
$usname = $_GET['ul'];
$uphone = $_GET['up'];
$uemail = $_GET['ue'];
$testlive = $_GET['test'];
$aff_id = $_GET['aff'];
$unique_id = $_GET['uid'];
$password = md5($_GET['pass']);
$mnumber = $_GET['meter'];
$bank = $_GET['bank'];
$camp = $_GET['camp'];
// Convert URL and Name split
$rurl = 'http://'.$_GET['rurl'];

// Split Name if no surname entered
if (strlen($usname) > 0) {
    $firstname = $uname;
    $lastname = $usname; // I have a first and lastname
} else {
    list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(" ",$uname,2); // I only entered my firstname
}
// Determine phone number format
$phoneformat = strpos($uphone,'-');
if($phoneformat === false) {
 // string - NOT found in haystack
 $phonesubmit = $uphone; 
} else {
    $phone1 = substr($uphone,0,3);
    $phone2 = substr($uphone,4,3);
    $phone3 = substr($uphone,8,4);
    $phonesubmit = $phone1.$phone2.$phone3;
}
// Determine Live or Test
$testlive = strtolower($testlive);
switch ($testlive) {
    case "test":
        $debug=true; //Set this to 'false' to redirect users
        $mpurl = 'http://stageapi.myprepaid.co.za/api/ConsumerRegisterRequest'; // Set to TEST environment
        break;
    case "live":
        $mpurl = 'https://api.myprepaid.co.za/api/ConsumerRegisterRequest'; // Set to LIVE environment
        break;
}

// Set Variables
$data = array("Email" => "$uemail", "Mobile" => "$phonesubmit", "Password" => "$password", "MeterNumber" => "$mnumber", "Bank" => "$bank", "CampaignID" => "$camp");

$response = sendJSONRequest($mpurl, $data);
if($debug) echo "Response: ".$response."<br />";

// If Customer Exists
if ($response == "0"){
    header ("location: https://www.myprepaid.co.za?affid=1040");
} else {

    $res = json_decode(file_get_contents($response), true);

    if($debug) echo "<pre>";
    if($debug) "\n" .print_r($res). "\n";
    $now = time();

    //Read values from response
    $rid = $res["ID"];
    $stat = $res["Status"];

    // Post to Trax

    $traxurl = "http://trax1.internetmarketingupstart.com/SP3o?"; //Trax URL
    $trax_post_string = 'aff_id='.$aff_id.'&aff_sub='.$unique_id;
    $trax_post_string .= '&aff_sub2='.urlencode($uname).'+'.urlencode($usname);
    $trax_post_string .= '&aff_sub3='.urlencode($uphone);
    $trax_post_string .= '&aff_sub4='.urlencode($uemail);
    $trax_post_string .= '&aff_sub5=';
    $trax = sendRequest($traxurl, $trax_post_string);

    if($debug) echo("\nTrax Result: {$trax} \n");

    // LOG ALL POSTS
    $logdetail = $aff_id.','.$unique_id.','.$testlive.','.$firstname.','.$lastname.','.$phonesubmit.','.$uemail.','.$rid.','.$stat.','.$trax;
    WriteLog("mypepaid",$logdetail);

    // ALL DONE -REDIRECT
    // Determine if ReturnURL contains variables
    $pos = strpos($rurl,'?');
    if($pos === false) {
     $urlconnector = '?';
    } else {
      $urlconnector = '&';
    }

    // Redirect to Confirmation page provided
    $URL=$rurl.$urlconnector.'un='.urlencode($firstname).'&ul='.urlencode($lastname).'&up='.urlencode($phonesubmit).'&ue='.urlencode($uemail).'&status='.urlencode($stat);
    if($debug) echo("Redirect to Confirmation URL:\n{$URL}");
    if(!$debug) header("Location: {$URL}");

    //Recheck the registration status after 50 seconds.
    while(time() <= $now + 50):
        if ($now == ($now + 50)):
            $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($response), true);
            $lateststat = $result["Status"];

            $NewURL=$rurl.$urlconnector.'un='.urlencode($firstname).'&ul='.urlencode($lastname).'&up='.urlencode($phonesubmit).'&ue='.urlencode($uemail).'&status='.urlencode($lateststat);
            echo "<script>javascript:window.location = '".$NewURL."';</script>";
        endif;
    endwhile;
}
?>
```

If you have other suggestions on how to accomplish this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: you could use AJAX through jQuery and call the php function to check if the process is finished. You can do that by setting an interval so jQuery keeps checking every x seconds until you get the response you want.

Comment: My client doesn't want me to use AJAX. He said that if possible, I'll use PHP but it seems that some things couldn't be done by using PHP alone that's why I incorporated javascript as seen on the last part of the code.

Comment: Without using AJAX you will have to tell JS to refresh the page at the specified interval until the PHP variable you are sending it is correct. Since PHP only send the data each time the page is requested if it ever updates the page must be refreshed so JS can access the data. This is where AJAX is helpful because you can do the same thing without refreshing the page

Comment: why would sleep not be applicable?

Comment: @hendr1x: Because sleep delays the execution of the whole script. I only want to put a delay the execution of the last portion of the script.

Comment: I don't get what you mean...sleep delays the code where you put it.

Comment: If you put sleep into while first line it will make script sleep for N seconds over and over again until while terms won't be fulfilled!